# How do I evaluate Typescript expression without using NgIf in HTML?

Tags: html, angular, frontend

I have looked alot for an answer, all I keep coming uo with is using the NgIf and I do NOT want to use that, instead
I am trying to use `[hidden]` . So please do not mark this as duplicate or "unclear", it is very clear (I am mentioning this because of previous unpleasant experiences with some "moderators").

I have been trying to make this work:
`[hidden]="vehicle.body==='sedan' "`

Is this valid? if it is not, can someone give me pointers to the correct way to make it work?

I have tried making aT/F varible in the TS component because I know for sure that something like `[hidden]="isHidden"` does work. but I want to evaluate the expression right there in the HTML part.

Thank you

Comment: Yes, `[hidden]="vehicle.body === 'sedan'"` is valid. If you see errors in the console, you can try with `vehicle?.body` (the [safe navigation operator](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#safe-navigation-operator) will prevent exceptions that would occur when `vehicle` is `undefined` or `null`).

Comment: Another point to consider: `hidden` is like setting `display: none`. So if you set a different `display` style with CSS or with style binding, it could prevent the element from being hidden.

Comment: what happened is that there was another ngif inside that tag, so i just added my condition to it with && instead on making separate [hidden] and it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's valid, although I would suggest removing the extraneous space at the end. Other consideration is what element you're applying the hidden attribute to. e.g. it's fine for divs, buttons but its worth checking if you're experiencing a problem unique to a particular type of control.

Side note: I know you said you don't want to use *ngIf, but curious as to why. If it's the typical problem where you don't want to affect your layout, you can consider using the ng-container structural directive since it doesn't affect the DOM. and is better for adding conditional display for entire sections, and any control e.g.

```
<ng-container *ngIf="condition">content
</ng-container>
```

Comment: what happened is that there was another ngif inside that tag, so i just added my condition to it with && instead on making separate [hidden] and it worked

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to hide an element based on conditons.The hide property hides the element from user view but its still present in the dom.

```
  <input class="txt" type="text" [hidden]="isHidden">
```

The *NgIf hides from both view and dom hence making it a better option but its entirely based on your usage.

```
   <input class="txt" type="text *ngIf="!isHidden">
```

Hiding and showing the element after rendering is fine But with Angular, we can build rich applications some of the components may use too many resources. And even though the component is hidden, the component will be attached to its DOM element. It will keep on listening for events. Angular keep on checking for changes related to data bindings. The component behavior still exists even though it is hidden.

The component and its children components will be tie up resources. Memory burden might be high which results in poor performance.
So it’s better to add or remove elements to the component element to the HTML DOM rather than hiding or showing them.

Answer (score 1):

Using **hidden** should solve your problem but i don't think you should use that.

There are two ways to hide UI,

1) *ngIf -> This removes element from DOM, -- Safe

2) hidden/ng-class -- > It just hides element from DOM so an attacker still can see your data/ UI by simply doing this **display: flex;** -- Not Safe

Choice is yours.

Happy Coding!